# Create complex installation script for Linux (Centos)

Tags: command-line, scripting, software-installation

For deployment of a complex system I would like to create a script that runs all compilations and set up. I am looking for an existing product that interpret installation scenario and performs all tasks, storing output in a log.

What I need is

- Run command on system, such as make /make install,
- Check if make and the like are exited with code 0 or not
- Run other commands such as modprobe and search their output for certain text, act upon existing/nonexisting text
- Chained tasks: if task A failed, do not try task B.
- Check existing files (such as NTP or sendmail configs) for certain lines and add these if not there (keeping the rest of the file).
- Intuitive logs with oitput of underlying processes.

While that can be achieved by writing a custom perl script, for instance, I would like to know if some ready-made software exists.

Preferably command line, but graphical interface is also ok.

Comment: Puppet, Chef, Salt, Ansible, etc., all are designed for these sorts of tasks...

Comment: as are make, rake, gulp, grunt ...

Comment: I use gulp indeed. Interesting, havent thought of it in this context, but it might be a good idea! @glennjackman I am afraid that writing Makefile is not funny at all.